# Primitive polynomial is prime if its image in field of fractions is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $A$ be a unique factorization domain, and let $K = S^{−1}A$, where
>   $S = A \setminus \{0\}$, be the field of fractions of $A$. Show that if $f ∈ A[X]$ is primitive and its image in $K[X]$ is prime, then $f ∈ A[X]$ is also
>   prime. Is this still true without the assumption that $f$ be primitive?

I think I need to prove by contradiction and use Gauss Lemma if $f,g \in A[X]$ is primitive then so is $fg$. But I am unable to figure it out. Can anyone give me some hints? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have $f\mid gh$ in $A[X]$. Then $fk=gh$, for some $k\in A[X]$.

Write $g=ag_0$, $h=bh_0$, $k=ck_0$, with $a,b,c\in A$ and $g_0$, $h_0$, $k_0$ primitive, so that
$$
cfk_0=abg_0h_0
$$
Up to associates, we can assume $c=ab$, because $fk_0$ and $g_0h_0$ are primitive.

Therefore we can restart with $f\mid gh$, $f\nmid g$, with $g$ and $h$ primitive.

Since $f$ is prime in $K[X]$, it must either divide $g$ or $h$ in $K[X]$.

Suppose, without loss of generality, $g=f\tilde{g}$, for some $\tilde{g}\in K[X]$. Collecting denominators we can write $\tilde{g}=\frac{a}{b}g_1$, where $a,b\in A$ and $g_1$ primitive in $A[X]$. Then
$$
bg=afg_1
$$
and, since $fg_1$ is primitive, we can assume $a=b$ (up to associates), so $g=fg_1$ in $A[X]$.

Comment: It seems you forgot to add a counterexample for the non-primitive case (which I find more instructive than a proof one can find in any algebra textbook).

Comment: @user26857 Do you mean something like $6x\mid 2x\cdot 3x$?